# Can I use ravendb in a javascript SPA

Tags: ravendb, single-page-application

I am developing a application that is using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) for most of the front end logic and was thinking of using sqlite for storage, but i have run into a few complications with it and need to switch to another NoSQL database.

I see on [ravendb](http://ravendb.net/)'s site that it was created in C# and you need a .net compiler. Most of the docs are for ASP MVC type application. I can not go this root because we are developing this as a tablet application with no microsoft based technologies on the client side ( because we want it to work with android and apple )

The server however will be .NET and so i figured this might be do able. Just wondering if this is worth pursuing and if anyone has had any experience using ravendb? Or should i go for mongodb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *possible* to expose RavenDB directly to a JavaScript application, sure.  But it's usually not recommended.  The main reason is security, but there are many other reasons to have a middle-layer.

For example, you often need a server-side location to perform application logic.  Not everything can be done in the database itself, and if you do it all in the application then you will probably send a lot more data to the app than it really needs.  Over the internet, that could mean a slow app.

The route many people take, is to use [ASP.Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api), or [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/), or another similar framework.  This gives you a way to expose REST endpoints that your JavaScript app can call.  You can connect to RavenDB from there.

Also, you seem to have the misconception that if you used ASP.Net MVC on the server that you couldn't target Apple or Android.  That's just false.  Whether you use a SPA approach or a traditional approach, you are delivering standards-based content, such as HTML, CSS, JSON and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I think i am starting to understand all of this a bit better

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use it. Actually RavenDB's server is a RESTful web service, which means you can work with it with any kinds of HTTP clients. These clients should be able to issue standard HTTP verbs like `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.

Answer (score 0):

ASP MVC is server side.  I still at a loss as to why you would want to expose your db to a clientside piece.  It is completely worth doing in a server side piece, but do not expose something like a db directly to your client.

Comment: There are situations when i dont want to call the server for info storage processes, it that not the whole reason for NoSQL based databases? Users can work offline on an app and then send the information once when they are online with a sync to the main db. It removes this "always connected" approach to SPA development and tablet app development. Should i just write to JSON and then send that maybe?

Comment: You don't want to try and setup ravendb on every client and you certainly don't want to call it directly.  I would create a web api and pass what you need back via JSON.